# AppCode returning undesired extension file results

Tags: appcode

When searching files, the results is providing me file results that I don't really need.

The kind of extensions are *.d *.dia *.o

Is there a way to fix this to behave as default and not showing them?

You can find attached a screenshot of one example que searching for "AppD", [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just realised that it is a folder related problem. By using git clone from my forked repository, everything became smooth and nice again.

[image]